# EF6 Code First Migration from Class Library Results in Blank Up/Down

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm rewriting some code from EF5 into EF6. As part of the process I'm attempting to split my database context logic out into a class library. This worked before when part of the main project but now results in blank up/down methods when running `add-migration`.

```
public class SLDBContext : DbContext
{
    public SLDBContext()
        : base("name=SLApi")
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SLDBContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TemplateFolder> TemplateFolders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Element> Elements { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
}
```

Running `add-migration MagicWombat` with my class library selected in the Package Manager Console gives me this:

```
public partial class MagicWombat : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

My seed methods are empty but I would expect it to create me some empty tables non-the-less. Obviously I'm missing something, but what?

Comment: Make sure you change the default project dropdown in the Package Manager Console to the class library before running `add-migration`.

Answer (score 1):

If your DbContext is no longer inside your startup project you need to use the `-StartUpProjectName` switch, so that EF can look at the config file there for the connection string.

```
add-migration MagicWombat -StartUpProjectName YourProject
```

if you've selected your class library as default in PM console, otherwise:

```
add-migration MagicWombat -ProjectName YouClassLibrary -StartUpProjectName YourProject
```